# Condiciones usando foreach en C#

Tags: c#, loops, condiciones

Necesito hacer un `foreach` en *C#*, en el cual se deben hacer varias condiciones como estas:

- `a` puede ser de tipo `1`, `2`, `3` o `4`.
- `b` puede ser de tipo `1`, `2`, `3` o `4`.

El conjunto de `a` más su tipo da un *ID* diferente dependiendo de la combinación.

Para lograr esto, intenté programar el siguiente código:

```
foreach (DocumentoMetadatosHijo hijo in documento.MetadatosHijo)
{
    //Decision 1
    List<Metadata> hijoList = new List<Metadata>();
    Dt hijodoctype = _taxo.dt.Where(
        x => x.id == hijo.TipoDocID.ToString() &&
        x.TipoComprobante == hijo.TipoComprobante
    ).FirstOrDefault();

    //Decision 2
    Dt hijodoctype2 = _taxo.dt.Where(
        x => x.id == hijo.TipoDocID.ToString() &&
        x.TipoIdentificacionPF == hijo.TipoIdentificacionPF
    ).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Hola Memo, bienvenido a [es.so], creo que no termino de comprender tu problema expuesto, exactamente, ¿cuál sería la pregunta?

Comment: @Memo me mareaste con lo de A o B, porque mejor nos explicas con el código que está añadido a la pregunta. :)

Comment: Claro que si, te explico, en la decision 1 se busca un id que es el x.id cuando lo encuentra si es A entonces se va a la siguiente condicion que es el tipo (estos valores estan cargados en un .json) cuando encuentra los dos debe insertar en una base de datos el valor que viene en el Json. ejemplo  {"id":"A","Tipocomprobante":"1","nombreTipo":"ife"}  ahi estaria diciendo que es una ife y es lo que insertaria en la base. Ejemplo 2  {"id":"A","Tipocomprobante":"2","nombreTipo":"Cedula"} ahi insertaria cedula y asi.  En caso de que encontrara que el id es B cambian sus tipos